# How to update a document in a subcollection, Firebase Firestore Web V9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i have a subcollection `transactions/pullout_requests/requests/`

[image]

I've managed to get and add data to it, but I don't know how to update a document in it. I have the document id of what I need to update. I can't find the `update` in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?hl=en&authuser=0#collection-group-query)

Comment: FYI: That isn't a collection group.  That's a subcollection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [update a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?hl=en&authuser=0#update-data) section of the documentation. In v9, that should be:

```
import { doc, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const docRef = doc(db, "transactions", "pullout_requests", "requests", "FeLv89oA6vN2wcJAmTo4");

await updateDoc(docRef, {
  capital: true
});
```